# Move Background Screen in libgdx game(android)

Tags: android, camera, screen, libgdx

I am developing a simple game using libgdx for Android where I want to move background scene as If Bird is moving forward. I tried various examples and code available on Internet to move or translate camera but to no avail. Kindly help me and suggest some code to accomplish this.

Here's is snippet from my code:

```
x+=0.1;
            trunk_rec.x-=10;
            trunk1_rec.x-=10;
            bird_rec.y-=5;
            if(trunk_rec.x<0)
            {
                trunk_rec.x=trunk1_rec.x=900;
            }

            camera.translate(1,0);
            camera.update();
            game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

            game.batch.begin();
            game.batch.draw(bg,0, 0,800,500);

            game.batch.draw(trunk,trunk_rec.x,trunk_rec.y);
            game.batch.draw(trunk,trunk1_rec.x,trunk1_rec.y);
            game.batch.draw(bird,bird_rec.x,bird_rec.y);

            game.batch.end();

            if(trunk_rec.x==bird_rec.x)
            {
                score++;
            }

            if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
            {
                bird_rec.y+=30;
            }

            if((trunk_rec.overlaps(bird_rec))|| trunk1_rec.overlaps(bird_rec) || bird_rec.y<10)
            {
                Gdx.app.exit();
                System.out.println("Score is "+score);
            }
```

I tried to move camera as well by using camera.position.

Thanx!

Comment: A better approach would be to move the bird instead of the background. Show us the code of the background/bird rendering.

Comment: @noone : but it is the requirement !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actors and Actions

use more then one ground actor to fill the screen width.

```
 if(isout){
 isout=false;
 ground1.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveTo(-ground.getWidth(),ground.getY(),duration),isDone));
 }
 Action isDone = new Action() {

    @Override
    public boolean act(float delta) {
                             isout=true;
                             ground1.setPosition(screenWidth,ground.getY());
        return true;
    }
};
```